# unable to create logs in aws S3 bucket using 'winston' and 's3-streamlogger'

Tags: node.js, windows, amazon-web-services

```
const winston = require('winston');
var S3StreamLogger = require('s3-streamlogger').S3StreamLogger;

var s3_stream = new S3StreamLogger({
    bucket: "bucket_name",
    access_key_id: "access_key_id",
    secret_access_key: "secret_access_key"
});

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            stream: s3_stream
        })
    ]
});

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
    winston.info('Hello Winston!');
    console.log("This is logging demo");
    logger.info('Logging is in progress');
    console.log("Consol Starting Lambda function");

    var responseCode = 200;  
    var responseBody = {
        message: "Hello !",
        input: event
    };
    var response = {
        statusCode: responseCode,
        headers: {
            "x-custom-header": "my custom header value"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(responseBody)
    };
    console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
    context.succeed(response);
};
```

On executing above code(successfully) on aws lambda. I am getting cloudwatch logs but there is nothing generated inside my S3 bucket.
I was hoping for a log file to be created over there but nothing created.
Am i lacking something in the code ?
My aim is to generate log file in amazon S3 bucket so that i can download the file for analysis.

Answer (score 4):

s3-streamlogger buffers content before uploading it to s3. By default it will buffer for 20 seconds, or 10kB of content (whichever is less) – so if your lambda function doesn't execute for at least 20 second, or write 10KB of logs nothing will be written before your function is suspended.

You could either specify smaller thresholds for the buffering via the `upload_every` and `buffer_size` options (see https://github.com/coggle/s3-streamlogger#upload_every), or manually flush the file after each request by calling `flushFile` on the stream.